# How do I know that TowelRoot worked

Tags: rooting, root-access

I'm trying to root my old android phone (Samsung Galaxy pocket Duos GT-S5302 with Gingerbread). I reset the phone to factory settings and then installed TowelRoot v3. But when I tapped the "make it ra1n" button, the phone just blinks and nothing happens. Does this mean it worked?

Comment: Isn't that an answer, @DeathMaskSalesman? You could of course also mention [Root Checker](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_989) apps, to make the thing complete :)

Comment: @Izzy I guess it is. Am I allowed to include your link in the answer?

Comment: @DeathMaskSalesman Of course. All content here is [CC-BY-SA](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) (see the page footer) ;)

Comment: Surely you're rooting for a reason, right?  Try doing the thing that required you to root in the first place, and see if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check whether a rooting procedure went successfully, there are two main ways.

---

### Root checker apps

If you prefer simpler things, you may choose one among the many [root checkers](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/tools_sysmaint#group_989). The list has been compiled by the trustworthy @Izzy, and I'll redirect you to it because I'm too lazy to reinvent the wheel today.

### Manual procedure

If you don't trust in root checkers, you may also choose to install a [Terminal emulator](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jackpal.androidterm). Once you open it, enter the `su` command, followed by enter. Next, enter the `whoami` command, followed by enter as well, and examine the response: if it's `root`, then you're rooted indeed. If it's anything else, then the procedure failed.

---

### Off-topic footnotes

From personal experience, TowelRoot usually congratulates if the rooting procedure was successful, so it may have failed in your case. If it has indeed failed, you may try your luck with the [modstrings](https://towelroot.com/modstrings.html).